# get values from json request

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i have this json response

> 2022-02-08 14:01:56,048 sdc-web-sockets-pp
> /moe.com/SMART/logs/srf/srf-web-sockets.log: 2022-02-08 14:01:50,308
> srf-web-sockets-pp-1 INFO  [null:-1] (executor-thread-19) Op16 -
> Station : id-00003:vdeURRi8v8evU8AZWEnIwtbrucvjdeZyJL42,
> MessageId: a8a3e920-88e7-11ec-8f9b-c904565fadef, request message:
> {"action":"Boot","messageId":"a8d3r920-88e7-11ec-8f9b-c9074d5fadef","type":"CALL","uniqueId":"a8a3e920-88e7-11ec-8f9b-c9074d5fadef","payload":"{"Vendor":"vendorname","PointModel":"pointname","PointSerialNumber":"123456789","firmwareVersion":"1.1.1.8"}"}

I need to get the specific vars.

ex:

vendname=vendorname

model= pointname

modelsn= 123456789

firmversion=1.1.1.8

Can someone help me get these values from the request?

this is what i have so far

```
def getvalboot(e):
        jsrqs = e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        if "BOOT" in jsrqs.upper():
            j1,j2ff = jsrqs.split(r"payload")
            j2f = j2ff.replace("\\", "")
            j2a = j2f[3:]
            size = len(j2a)
            j2 = j2a[:size - 2]
            stud_obj = json.loads(j2)
            print("1: ",stud_obj['Vendor'])
```

Ok, this works but im pretty sure there is a better way to do this, any idea?

Comment: Updated the question with what i have so far

Answer (score 0):

It is harder to help when you don't share a bit of code for context.

Assuming we have a context like this:

```
message = some_api_call()
```

I would try this:

```
data = message['payload'] #message is a dictionary and we'd like to access the payload/data

vendname = data['Vendor']
model = data['PointModel']
modelsn = data['PointSerialNumber']
firmversion = data['firmwareVersion']
```

I don't like the idea of creating a variable for each info, but since it is a small bit of code and we only have one row of data returned, it might not be relevant to discuss that.

Comment: data = jsrqs['payload'] 
TypeError: string indices must be integers

i dont know if this is important but i pass the json request manually, it doesnt get it from a request

Comment: My suggestion might work if you try it like this
`data = jsrqs['request message']['payload'] `
You still haven't provided much context on what are we calling at :
`jsrqs = e.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c")`
So, this is as much as I could help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the json libary wich comes defualt in built inn with python. The json libary can be used to convert the json file to a dictionary.

```js
import json

f = open(r"file path", "r")
jsonf = f.read()
dict = json.loads(jsonf)
f.close()
```

Comment: thnks, i pass the value with copy/past not from a request